# Upload a word file with primary key filename using laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to insert data wit a file into database.

So I'm using the following code :

```
public function store(Request $req){
        $req->validate([

        'modele_contrat' => 'required',
        'fichier.*' => 'required|file|max:5000|mimes:docx,doc'
        ]);

        $fileModel = new Model_Contrat;

        if($req->file()) {
            $fileName = $req->file('fichier')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath = $req->file('fichier')->storeAs('uploads/modeles_contrat', $fileName, 'public');
            $fileModel->modele_contrat = $req['modele_contrat'];
            $fileModel->fichier = $req->file('fichier')->getClientOriginalName();
            $fileModel->save();

            return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Added successfully.']); 

        }
   }
```

Everything is fine except i found a blockage at the uploader filename, I want the file to be named with the primary key of the inserted row, for example if the inserted row has id = 7 the files should be named 7.docx.

I tried that :

```
 $fileName = $req->id;
```

but doesn't work.

If you have any idea please help

Comment: Find last row in rable `$lastRow = Model::order_by('created_at', 'desc')->first();` then use it's id +1 to `$filePath = $req->file('fichier')->storeAs('uploads/modeles_contrat', $lastRow->id+1.$fileName, 'public');`

Comment: @mafortis thank you for your help , I tried what did u say , but I'm getting : `Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Model_Contrat::order_by()"`

Comment: My bad there is a typo `Model::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();` don't forget to change `Model` to your model name.

Comment: it works , thank you , execpt I edit it to : `Model::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->value('id');`